# Can I use Outlook's rules to automatically send an email (not forward an email) each time a new message arrives?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

I have a work email account in Outlook 2010, and I want to send an email to another, non-Outlook email account each time a new message arrives in Outlook. How do I do this? In the Rules Wizard I don't see an action for "send a message" or anything like that. Is my only option to use VBA?

I don't want to *forward* the email from Outlook to my other account because I'm restricted from forwarding work emails to personal accounts. I just want to send a completely new email, with a subject of "new email" or something.

Comment: You can probably at least break it up: You should be able to configure Outlook to "Start an application" and then just find a command line program or script that'll send email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible.

You could use a rule to forward an email to another account (just mentioning it as an option, even though you mentioned you're not allowed to do this), but you can't write a custom email to a custom person.

I think it would be easier to setup your other mail client to also receive the email you get in outlook.

Comment: Any update for Office365 in 2023? Useful feature to generate a kind of notification.

Answer (score 0):

How about running a script to send the new email.

https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/send-a-new-message-when-a-message-arrives/

Answer (score -3):

How about an automated response? (normally used for vacations etc.)

Comment: Won't an automatic response automatically reply to the person who sent me an email? I don't want to respond to everyone who writes me; I want to send an email to another account I own, basically notifying me that I received an email in Outlook.

Comment: Indeed, out of office reply or anything alike is not what you want. This won't work.